# How to create an immutable array within a mutable array in scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

So I am trying to create an immutable array of size 10 within a mutable array in scala. In this immutable array I want to store key, value pairs. so far I have this mutable array:

```
val array1 = mutable.ArrayBuffer[Option[IndexedSeq[(A,B)]]]()
```

Now to create an immutable buffer in array1 would I just do:

```
array1(0) = immutable.ArrayBuffer[](10)
```

I am confused on what would go within the brackets of the immutable buffer for the type.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do you want to do? You are trying to assign a `immutable.ArrayBuffer` to the first position of `array1`, is what what you want to do?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes that is what I am going for

Comment: Well `array1` is an `mutable.ArrayBuffer[Option[IndexedSeq[(A,B)]]]` thus the elements must be `Option[IndexedSeq[(A,B)]]` not an `immutable.ArrayBuffer` so what you want to do doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `immutable.ArrayBuffer`.  `ArrayBuffer` is mutable.

Trait `IndexedSeq` can correspond to both immutable and mutable collections, so you have options what to use as your inner elements:

```scala
type A = Int
type B = Int

val array1 = mutable.ArrayBuffer[Option[IndexedSeq[(A,B)]]]()

// Adds immutable Vector
array1 += Some(IndexedSeq[(A, B)]( (1,2), (3,4) ))

// Adds mutable ArrayBuffer
array1 += Some(ArrayBuffer[(A, B)]( (1,2), (3,4) ))
```

Note, since your inner element is `Option[IndexedSeq[...]]`, you need to wrap the elements you are adding in `Some`.